# Are the classes in TOR *really* mirrored across factions?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I know that the intent in The Old Republic was that the factions would be balanced by having the same classes available to each faction, albeit with different names and animations.

But after playing the game for a while, I'm not sure I believe this anymore.

One example:

While it's true that the Republic Commando and the Imperial Bounty Hunter share the same abilities, the bounty hunter uses "Heat", which goes from 0 - 100, and the Commando uses "Ammo", which goes from twelve to zero.

Comparing one of their first abilities: [Rocket Punch](http://www.torhead.com/ability/fMlDnph) and [Stockstrike](http://www.torhead.com/ability/fycNIyp), the Bounty Hunter's version uses 16 heat, and the Commando's version uses 2 Ammo.

Converting Ammo to an equivalent amount of heat 2/12 ~> **17** heat.

Am I missing something, or do Bounty Hunters get fractionally better abilities?

**Are there other differences between the faction classes**, such as talent trees, or even non-mirrored abilities? Are the classes in TOR *really* mirrored across factions, or only approximately?

Comment: It is actually 16.66 heat... which is roughly the equivalent ;)

Comment: they are mirror images for all purposes. Maybe one ability does .0342 more damage than the other, but probably another ability does -.0323... Nothing that really makes any difference except for the most die-hard minmaxers (and since abilities change every build, I wouldn't worry about it)

Comment: Yes, they are **supposed** to be mirrors. Jedi classes are exact mirrors (played them up to 20, no difference), learn the same skills at the same levels. BH/Agents and Soldiers/Smugglers are **supposed** to be mirrors, but using mechanisms a bit different to make it less obvious. This makes them a bit unbalanced towards one side or the other though, which is supposed to be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found one case where an ability is different between the mirrors, but even beyond that there are definitely some differences between how the mirrored abilities themselves play out. The differences mainly seem to be in the animations used (and the speed differences therein) as well as travel time from projectile to target. As such, most of these differences have very little effect except in PVP, where a few seconds can be critical.

Just for the sake of context, here are the mirrors:

```
  - Jedi Knight      <-> Sith Warrior
  - Jedi Consular    <-> Sith Inquisitor
  - Republic Trooper <-> Bounty Hunter
  - Smuggler         <-> Imperial Agent
```

Obviously maintaining a list of every single difference would be unwieldy not to mention probably end up outdated, but here are some differences I've found to illustrate my point:

---

- Bounty Hunter's "Unload" doesn't get interrupted if you take damage, but the Trooper's Full Auto does. This makes the Bounty Hunter's ability better.
- The Bounty Hunter's Death From Above starts applying its damage immediately, compared to the Trooper's Mortar Volley which takes a few seconds before damage starts being applied.
- The Sith Inquisitor's Shock does its damage immediately, whereas the
  Jedi Consular's Project ability has a longer animation and a travel
  time.
- Smuggler's Dirty Kick stops the forward movement of the smuggler,
  where as the Imperial Agent's version does not stop the forward
  movement of the agent.
- The Imperial Agent's Flash Bang is on a 60 second cooldown, but the
  Smuggler's Flash Grenade is on a 90 second cooldown. They otherwise
  appear to be identical. [They plan to patch it soon.](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=1288016)
- The Imperial Agent's Backstab happens instantly. The Smuggler's Back
  Blast animation takes longer.
- The Imperial Agent's Explosive Probe animation is quick and damage happens almost instantly, whereas the Smuggler's Sabotage Charge has a longer animation plus the damage isn't applied until the charge travels to the target.
- I see at least one example of ability difference (assuming TorHead
  can be trusted). The Consular gets a level 46 ability, [Unity](http://www.torhead.com/ability/fdpfJz0/unity), which
  lets them and their companion reduce damage by 50% for 15 seconds.
  The Inquisitor has a level 46 ability called [Sacrifice](http://www.torhead.com/ability/3wcqmoN/sacrifice) which nearly
  kills their companion, but heals themselves 40%. Pretty different
  effects. **This is biggest difference I've seen, and haven't heard of any others like this.**

---

**So to answer your question directly, no, they aren't perfectly mirrored.** I think the animation speeds have a much larger impact on how the mirrored classes play differently, as opposed to the minor round-off problem in the conversion such as that between heat and ammo. But even then, the mirroring is close enough that it probably won't matter to anyone except in PVP.

Comment: The difference in the Crit heal talents is a typo. They both give 10/20/30%.

Comment: Did not know that! I'll remove it.

Comment: Pssst! There's at least one pair of abilities that aren't mirrored. Include it in your answer, and you'll be that much closer to earning the bounty.

Comment: @RavenDreamer  Not sure if it's the one you had in mind, but I think I found an ability difference. Added it.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't help that **Unity** is bugged and has the opposite of its intended effect.

Comment: Your answer got auto-converted to community wiki. Since you've been the only one editing it, I've reverted it back.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "animations"?  The character animations aren't synced perfectly with casting, and you can safely ignore them; they don't affect how long the ability takes to execute.  Is it just the difference in travel time, which may be reflected in the animation?

Comment: @MatthewRead Some of this may have changed. I haven't played the game since about the time that I posted this answer, but there are (or were) definitely some animations which could not be ignored... your ability would not go off until the animation was complete. Travel time was on aspect of that, but in the case of Project vs Shock, the projectile also took longer to start flying in the first place from the time you pressed the key, because the Jedi animation "casting" was longer and the projectile didn't start until the animation was complete.

Comment: @Sterno Ah OK, thanks for following up.  I do think some of the abilities have been corrected to I might go through the patch notes and update this :)

Answer (score -1):

They are balanced, but not mirrored, for example, the Republic Smuggler (either sub) is stronger than the Imperial Operative, but what the Operative lacks in strength, it makes up for in stealth. And the Smuggler is also much faster than the Imperial Sniper, but what the Sniper lacks in speed, it makes up for in range and strength.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few discrepancies between classes but for the most part they are the same. Many differences are with animations--the Sith Sorcerer and Jedi Sage have abilities that are the same but the Sage's animation has a travel time while the Sorcerer's is instant. This is of little consequence because you can still move while the animation is firing if you're not casting/channeling an ability.

Some more significant differences do exist between the Trooper and Bounty Hunter that I know of. The Bounty Hunter's Unload will always tick three times even when they suffer pushback from being attacked; the Trooper's takes longer to start hitting and can actually lose one of the three hits. Another issue exists between Death From Above and Mortar Volley where Mortar Volley doesn't actually start doing damage until 2.2 seconds into the channel where DFA does damage at 1, 2, and 3 seconds into the channel. These issues are reported issues and will hopefully be fixed.

As for Ammo versus Heat, they are the same. The Trooper regenerates ammo marginally faster than the Bounty Hunter cools down which balances out this marginal ability cost difference.

Comment: Do you have a source for that last paragraph?

Comment: Math is my source. Using that 1 ammo = 8.33 heat, you can look at regen tables: 0-20 heat vents 5/sec, 9.6-12 Ammo regens 0.625/sec. 0.625 ammo per sec * 8.33 heat per ammo = 5.21 heat per sec. This holds up for the remaining regen rates.

Comment: Then where are the regen tables you're citing?

Comment: Here's my citation: load up the game, make a character, and look at it.

Comment: I *did*, and it listed Ammo regen at .60 per second. So, for the second time, I think you're citing wrong information!